# Invalid sdkVersion while running react native project

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, react-native

I'm stuck on the initial part of react native app building. I'm using create-react-native-app pkg to create the project and When I run the android version app through "yarn run android" command I get the error below:

```
Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 13.0.0, 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 16.0.0, 17.0.0, 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 22.0.0, 23.0.0, 24.0.0, 25.0.0, 7.0.0, 8.0.0, 9.0.0
```

It's a windows machine. Node v10.0.0, npm v5.6.0, Java 1.8 & android studio is already installed and working I added variety of APIs through android studio.. currently I have 17-23-24-26 installed in Sdk platforms.
And I get the following error on real android device:

```
uncaught Error: console.error: React Native version mismatch.

Javascript version: 0.53.0
Native version: 0.52.0

Make sure that you have rebuilt the native code. If the problem persists try clearing the Watchman and packager caches with 'watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache.
```

I didn't find solution ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this issue by installation of `Expo XDE` window app.

the problem was missing **schema-27.0.0.json** file in directory:

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Expo
```

[download Expo XDE](https://github.com/expo/xde/releases)

> schema.json version is depend on react native npm version that you installed.
>   [documents here](https://expo.io/tools#xde)

Comment: How are these`schema-##.0.0.json` files generated, can they be copied from https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/tree/master/packages/xdl/caches ???

Comment: I think it will be created during installation, but you can manually put this file ;) @BigRich

Answer (score 0):

open your build.gradle file ( located in YOUR_PROJECT/android/app/build.gradle ) and validate your `compileSdkVersion`

**EDIT**

if you are using expo check `sdkVersion` in your app.json file and be sure it is same as one in package.json file

Comment: goodness.. invalid sdk is gone.. but mismatch error on device still exists:

React native version mismatch

javascript version: 0.55.4
native version: 0.50.3

Comment: I've reduced the react-native version to 0.50.3 and it solved. Thnx alot

Answer (score 0):

In the file app.json put `"sdkVersion": "36.0.0",`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "name-app",
    "slug": "name-app",
    "sdkVersion": "36.0.0",
...
```